# There is no "Edit Custom Style" on context menu of a control in Delphi XE4

Tags: delphi, styles, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

I am using delphi xe4 for developing ios apps, for styling controls I have read that there should be a "Edit Custom Style" when you right-click on a control, but there is no such option for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer,

There is no "Edit Custom Style" on FireMonkey Mobile form, but instead you can do it as below,

1.Drop a StyleBook on the form and assign it to the form

2.Double click on StyleBook, the editor will open

3.Load one of default styles

4.Without closing the editor, open the Structure view, all of the styles are here

5.Select style you want to change, and change it via Property window

6.You can save the new style for future use

Answer (score 0):

This is a relic of XE2...I think that's how it was done back then (the help file in XE4 still says so, but it also says its category is "FMX|XE2").  Nowadays you have to go via the StyleBook property of the form. See here for details: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Customizing_the_Design_of_a_FireMonkey_Application#Step_2:_Apply_an_existing_style_to_your_application_at_design_time

Comment: That will allow you to build a custom style from the ground up, but to modify a built in still will be *much* more work.

Comment: @Sherlock70
The menu is exists on Firemonkey desktop application but it seems that is has been removed from Firemonkey mobile application. Do you have any idea?

Comment: The option exists for mac os application, but it is not available for iOS apps